# MATLAB Greyscale 12 bit to 8 bit

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to create an algorithm to convert a greyscale from 12 bit to 8 bit.

I got a greyscale like this one:

[image]

The scale is represented in a Matrix. The problem is, that the simple multiplication with 1/16 destroys the first grey-columns.

Here the Codeexample:

```
in =[
    1 1 1 3 3 3 15 15 15 63 63 63;
    1 1 1 3 3 3 15 15 15 63 63 63;
    1 1 1 3 3 3 15 15 15 63 63 63; 
    1 1 1 3 3 3 15 15 15 63 63 63
];   
[zeilen spalten] = size(in); 

eight = round(in/16);   
imshow(uint8(eight));
```

Destroy mean, that the New Columns are Black now

Comment: What do you mean by "destroy"?

Comment: 12 bit to 8 bit or vice versa ? Your title says one thing and the question says the opposite.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, 12 to 8

Comment: it would be easier to help if you provide the exact lines of code you used

Answer (score 4):

Simply rescale the image so that you divide every single element by the maximum possible intensity that corresponds to a 12-bit (or `2^12 - 1 = 4095`) unsigned integer and then multiply by the maximum possible intensity that corresponds to an 8-bit unsigned integer (or `2^8 - 1 = 255`).

Therefore:

```
out = uint8((255.0/4095.0)*(double(in)));
```

You need to cast to `double` to ensure that you maintain floating point precision when performing this scaling, and then cast to `uint8` so that the image type is ensured to be 8-bit.  You have cleverly deduced that this scaling factor is roughly (1/16) (since `255.0/4095.0 ~ 1/16`).  However, the output of your test image will have its first 6 columns to surely be zero because intensities of 1 and 3 for a 12-bit image are just too small to be represented in its equivalent 8-bit form, which is why it gets rounded down to 0.  If you think about it, for every 16 intensity increase that you have for your 12-bit image, this registers as an equivalent single intensity increase for an 8-bit image, or:

```
12-bit --> 8-bit
   0   -->   0
   15  -->   1
   31  -->   2
   47  -->   3
   63  -->   4
   ... --> ...
  4095 --> 255
```

Because your values of 1 and 3 are not high enough to get to the next level, these get rounded down to 0.  However, your values of 15 get mapped to 1, and the values of 63 get mapped to 4, which is what we expect when you run the above code on your test input.